# App linking to root instead of actual application on redirect

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm having some trouble working with paths in Django. I have python experience but not Django experience at all.

Here is what I have

`templates/AppName/base.html`

```
<header id="header">
    <div id="logo">
    <div id="top_menu">
        Home | Calendar | About |
    <a href="/contactus">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

`template/AppName/contact_us.html`

```
{% extends 'Orchestrator/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>New post</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

`AppName/urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'AppName'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('contactus/', views.contact_us, name='contactus')
]
```

`AppName/views.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import ContactUs


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'AppName/base.html')


# Forms #
def contact_us(request):
    form = ContactUs()
    return render(request, 'AppName/contact_us.html', {'form': form})
```

`AppName/forms.py`

```
from django import forms

class ContactUs(forms.Form):
    firstname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

`urls.py` (Root one)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('AppName/', include('AppName.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

So, the rendering of the starting page, meaning
`127.0.0.1:8000/AppName`
Works just fine, but when I want to make the `Contact Us` button redirect to `AppName/contactus`, `Django` is actually redirecting to `127.0.0.1/contactus`.

Any idea on how to solve this?

EDIT: Added `root/urls.py`

Comment: What does your project urls.py look like?

Comment: Edited the question adding `urls.py`

Answer (score -1):

Well, it turns out that the problem was present at the `base.html`.

Instead of `/contactus` it should be `contactus/`

Using `contactus/` actually redirects to `127.0.0.1/AppName/contactus`

EDIT: From further answers, the best way to handle this is actually using

`{% url "contactus" %}`

So paths are not hardcoded

Comment: Nope. What it should be is `{% url "contactus" %}`. You don't want to hardcode any url in your templates or code, you want to use Django's url resolver to reslove them for you.

Comment: I highly recommend naming your urls and using `{% url "url_name_goes_here" %}` in your templates. It avoids issues like the one you were having, and an added benefit is that it makes changing your urls really easy.

Comment: Thanks! Will use that then